# SOAP UI validates improper fault structure

Tags: validation, soap, xsd, schema, soapui

Can you help me understand why SOAP UI (v4.0.1) validates the below structure even though it should be non compliant to standard schema

```
 <soapenv:Body>
      **<code>FOUTNUMMER :  RRC073</code>**
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Provider Error Occured.</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: Please recheck, `soap fault` might be in the schema.

Comment: No , i'm talking about <code>FOUTNUMMER :  RRC073</code> , placed in between Body and Fault.